# How is connecting to a specific Wifi network breaking Xdebug?

Tags: macos, networking, wifi, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using a Macbook and connecting to a new Wifi network. When I have the network *on*, I can browse the internet, but Xdebug will not connect. When I have the network *off*, the opposite is true. When I connect to a different network (i.e. tethering on my iPhone's 3G network), I can do both.

I don't have access to the router (I'm at an Italian AirBnb), I've tried a VPN, and SSH port forwarding wouldn't make sense because I'm trying to connect to a local MAMP installation.

Is there a way I can get around this networking issue?

**Update**

I am trying to connect to `test.dev`, which is pointing to `127.0.0.1`, which a MAMP PRO vhost picks up on, pointing to a folder on the same laptop.

Trying to connect on different ports, such as 9001 or 9090 also does not work.

When I am tethered to my phone, the debugging works, and `xdebug.remote_log` reports the following:

```
Log opened at 2017-03-17 09:18:26
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init ...></init>

...

<- run -i 43
Log closed at 2017-03-17 09:18:31
```

When I am connected to the problem network, the debugging does not work, and `xdebug.remote_log` reports the following:

```
Log opened at 2017-03-17 09:22:28
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-03-17 09:22:28
```

A `phpinfo()` reports:

```
xdebug

xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.7
IDE Key Aucun
Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    512 512
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Comment: 1) xdebug will not connect where? 2) Collect and show xdebug log for situation when it works and when it does not. So far the problem might be in the IP it tries to connect to. 3) Showing your php.ini will be useful as well.

Comment: You have `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`. And you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back=On`. Now -- in both successful and not attempts it tries to connect to `::1:9000` .. which is IPv6. It's possible that when you connected to that WiFi network, IPv6 does not work correctly or not available at all. You are also using xdebug v2.2.x .. while latest is 2.5.1.

Comment: **My suggestions are**: 1) `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1` -- specify IPv4 here; 2) `xdebug.remote_connect_back=Off` -- so xdebug does not autodetect IP but connects to a provided IPv4 address. You may also try giving IPv4 interface priority over IPv6 one in your Mac settings -- may help as well. Updating xdebug may also help (it should have better handling of connections over IPv6). Those are ideas for now.

Comment: @LazyOne It worked! All I had to do was set `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` and Xdebug started working again. The logs now read `Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000`. I did not have to make any other changes. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: @LazyOne suggestions fixed it for me!